# Laravel / Yajra Datatable - Order table by added column

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

Is there a way to order a datatable by an added column? I couldn't figure it out .

Example:

```
return datatables()->of(Restaurant::select('id','denumire')->where('id_stare',1)->with(['orders'=>  function($q) use($startDate, $endDate){

                $q->where('created_at', '>=',$startDate->toDateTimeString())->where('created_at', '<=',$endDate->toDateTimeString());

            }])
            )
            ->addIndexColumn()

            ->addColumn('suma', function(Restaurant $restaurant) {

                $suma = $restaurant->orders->sum(function($item){
                    return $item->total;
                });

                return intval($suma);

            })
            ->make(true);
```

In front i use the JavaScript DataTable framework , but the default ordering is not doing nothing

Comment: you need to use `front end order` like https://datatables.net/reference/option/order and it will be fetch from server as your using server side render

Comment: Tried it , but nothing happens ( if i try to order by first row which is a default column not an added one, is working , but for the added column, nothing happens).

Comment: what code you have tried ?

Comment: order: [[ 2, "asc" ]] // which is the added column (not working)
 order: [[ 1, "asc" ]] // which is not an added column (working)